# getting error with atribute 'str' object has no atribute 'read'

Tags: python, image, csv, flask, opencv

I want to upload images with flask API, but I got an error in this code.

```
def model_predict(img_path, model):
    img = img_path

    x = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(img.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    x = cv2.resize(x,(224,224))
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    images = np.vstack([x])/ 255.0

    preds = model.predict(images)
    if preds[0] > 0.5:
      return "Good"
    else:
      return "Bad"
```

and the error is

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
> any solutions?

Comment: In your own words, where your code says `img.read()`, what do you expect the value of `img` to be? Why? Did you test that assumption? What do you think should happen when you call `.read()` on that? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

img_path is a string. If you want to read from a file, do

```
img = open(img_path)
```